# Identifying which diodes are on in a full wave rectifier

Tags: diodes, rectifier, ideal

[image]

For the circuit above, I am looking for which diodes are on during the positive and negative cycle. Is it safe to assume that I should just trace the path of the current based on where the diode is pointing?

For example, during the positive cycle, the current will enter node 1, then goes through D2 and D3. On the other hand, during the negative cycle, it will enter node 3, then D4 until it reaches D1. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: This [image](https://www.elprocus.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/3.jpg) from [this source](https://www.elprocus.com/full-wave-rectifier-circuit-working-theory/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct with regard to which diodes are conducting.

Where the current "enters" and "exits" depends on whether you view current as electron flow (ie. coming from the negative terminal of the current source) or "conventional" current flow (ie. coming from the positive terminal).  That's a matter of habit and local customs.  Your statement is proper for conventional current flow.